# Getting a click to select from a select box

Tags: javascript, django, zurb-foundation

I'm using Django and Zurb-foundation.

On a certain page I have on the one hand a bunch of items organized in a table, displaying their properties. On the other hand, on the same page I have a form which contains a select box, the elements in which are the previously mentioned items. Now in principle as the number of items grows larger it will get boring finding one in the form's select box. I would like to, if you click on one of those items being displayed on the table, have that same item be selected in the select box.

How do I do this? I know absolutely nothing about javascript, but if you can at least mention the relevant key concepts, I'll learn them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zvCvL/5/

Although I have left several comments detailing how this should be done, I will summarize below:

- Loop through each of the items and their descriptions using Django's templating engine's looping feature (this part is going to be left up to you to figure out, but I have left you a link in the fiddle to get you started) For example, you will be adding these to your `tbody` in each of your loops:

  ```
  <!-- loop iteration one -->
  <tr>
      <td class="item1">Item 1</td>
      <td class="item1">The first item</td>
  </tr>
  ```

  Do not forget, however, that my method requires that a unique name be given to the `td`'s in every iteration.
- Then, you can work on the dropdown. This will require a simplier loop, just adding these to the `ul` which acts as your dropdown:

  ```
  <!-- loop iteration one -->
  <li class="item1"><a>Item 1</a></li>
  ```

  Once again, this requires a unique class name, yet one that corresponds to the class name given to the item in table.
- Finally, you have your JavaScript to take care of. Simply, you can check to see if the user is hovering over an `li`, check which class it belongs to, and apply some sort of color to all elements which have that same class. Of course, one caveat is that this will act upon **all** list elements. I'll leave it up to you to change that as needed.

Hopefully this helps! (The ultimate result is: http://jsfiddle.net/zvCvL/5/embedded/result/)

Comment: Another note: I decided to check for when the user hovers over the `li`. You appear to want the user to click. As my JS comments in the fiddle explain, that's pretty simple to do.

Comment: Thank's a lot! This will be enough for me to figure out how to do what I wanted. I'll upload the final result when I got it. There's only the technical difficulty that in my case the drop-down is being generated authomatically as part of a form in Django, but that I'll manage. Thanks!!
Oh just one last detail. Like I said I understand zero about javascript. So, where should I insert the js code? Inside <script>, I imagine, but where exactly on the html? Head, body, anywhere at all?

Comment: So, I was trying to get your idea working exactly the way I wanted: clicking on a list selects an option from the dropdown. Do you understand why the following isn't working?
http://jsfiddle.net/K7dKC/1/

Comment: You were correct about it being inside a `script` tag. As for where it should go, it would be best to place it somewhere after all of the elements have been placed in the `body` by Django (so towards the end).

Comment: Could you please have a look at the code I wrote in jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I was working on it. Take a look at my comments in this: http://jsfiddle.net/P2t82/2/ I have forked your original, and added comments detailing what I have changed. With the dropdown/options that you are using, the syntax changes a bit

Comment: Hi again :-) So, I finally got it almost working the way I wanted. You click the table and that selects an option from the dropdown:
http://jsfiddle.net/oneloop/92NtR/1/
Now what I don't understand is why it seems to stop working the second time you click it. Any clue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44123/discussion-between-oneloop-and-nmagerko)

Comment: I finally did it. The solution was to user .prop('selected', true) instead of .attr! Here it is, fully functional:
http://jsfiddle.net/oneloop/92NtR/
I wouldn't have managed it without you though, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I apologize for my absence. I did not realize you wanted to select the table - I misread! But I am very happy to hear about your success